# Use of Thumbnail Folder in media/image directory in Shopware

Tags: thumbnails, shopware

I am new to Shopware.

I want to know what is the use of folder media/image/thumbnail, when all the thumbnail images are stored as nested folder structure for example (aa/20/e4).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the [MediaService Documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-media-service/?_ga=2.25709819.770407758.1515367715-1746788364.1514039528#the-problem)

### The problem

Since the beginning of Shopware, the `media` files were organized in a directory called media with subdirectories for each media type, e.g. image, video, and so on. Inside a sub-directory, every file has just been thrown in. The problem is that, if you have a huge amount of media files, file operations get very slow, especially on Windows systems.

For that reason, we decided to apply commonly used techniques to our media management and introduce the new MediaService.

### The solution

The main goal of the MediaService is to abstract and handle all file operations, so that you don't have to worry about solving common problems associated with it. The key idea to keep in mind is that you shouldn't directly perform any file system operation on your files. Should you need to read, move or delete your files, you should always use the MediaService.

In the past, the most common use-case was to load a path like `media/image/my-fancy-image.png` from the database and, during the template render process, prepend the base url to it. These paths are still used, but now as virtual paths. These paths identify your files, and are used by the MediaService to access them. Note that the actual file will not be in this exact location in your file system. It's up to the MediaService to retrieve the real path from this virtual path.

Comment: Can I integrate MesdiaService in Bootstrap.php file in my Backend Plugin?

If yes, can you tell me how?

Comment: You should read the documentation which i wrote above. It's all descriped there.